# Jarring comma usage in "Freedom of the Will"

Tags: commas

I'm reading "Freedom of the Will" by Jonathan Edwards, and I'm finding a lot of comma usage that seems jarring. As I understand it, the comma is generally used to indicate a pause in thought (among other uses), but there are commas placed in the text where a pause feels unnatural. Is there an older/archaic rule for the comma that Edwards is using, or is it just a style that is no longer used?

Comment: Frankly, this calls for speculation. Comma usage can get quite complicated and unless you post an example, the question is very moot.

Comment: If you're looking for historical answers, you should tell us when the book was first published.

Comment: In the 18th and 19th centuries, some authors used commas much more frequently than they are used today. Many texts from that era have edited out the superfluous commas. But I have no idea what the rules for the extra commas were back then, if there were indeed rules.

Comment: Can you please provide a passage from the work that relates to your question?

Comment: This [New York Times opinion piece](https://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/04/09/fanfare-for-the-comma-man/) seems to suggest that the pauses in thought in 18th and 19th century literature were pretty subjective.

Comment: Worse than this?  http://quotegeek.com/television-quotes/red-dwarf/20/

Comment: There is [no common standard for comma use in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf), even today; and when Jonathan Edwards wrote, there was even less. He was a noted orator, and his written speeches don't come close to representing his oral presentation. Certainly you can't depend on his comma usage to be anything other than idiosyncratic. Executive Summary: If you're gonna read stuff that old, you gotta expect it to look weird.

Comment: The book was published in 1754.  There weren't even "standard" dictionaries, much less standardized punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> There is [no common standard for comma use in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf), even today; and when Jonathan Edwards wrote, there was even less. He was a noted orator, and his written speeches don't come close to representing his oral presentation. Certainly you can't depend on his comma usage to be anything other than idiosyncratic. Executive Summary: If you're gonna read stuff that old, you gotta expect it to look weird.